# HTTP request in AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm Working on AngularJs about a week and I'm trying to insert a value into mysql database through a PHP.

my `form` look like this

```
    <form ng-model="far_form" name="far_reg" ng-submit="register(far_reg.$valid)" novalidate="true" 
        ng-controller= "farform_contr">
        <input type="text" id="First Name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="far.first_name" >
        <input type="text" id="Email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="far.email">
        <input type="text" id="Mobile" placeholder="Mobile" ng-model="far.mobile">
    </form>
```

And `Controler is`

```
.controller('farform_contr',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.register = function(isValid) {
            if (isValid) {
                $http({
                        method  : 'POST',
                        url     : 'submit.php',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data    : $scope.far, //forms user object
                        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
                }).
                        success(function(data, status) {
                            console.log(far);
                            $scope.status = status;
                            $scope.data = data;
                        })
            }else{

                  alert('Form is not valid');
            }
        }
    }]);
```

I have couple of other controller in the same file Which are working fine.

`submit.php` is

```
<?php
    $post_date = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode($post_date);
    $name=$data['first_name'];
    $email=$data['email'];
    $mobile=$data['mobile'];
    echo "<script>alert('$name')</script>";
    echo "<script>alert('$email')</script>";
    echo "<script>alert('$mobile')</script>";
?>
```

All the echo's are returning null I don't know where i'm going wrong.

Comment: When you use `$http` service, the way of retrieving response is `argument.data` in success function. Have you got any response in success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably need to serialize the json before decoding it and specify the content type to "application/json"

```
$http({
method  : 'POST',
url     : 'submit.php',
dataType: 'json',
data    : JSON.stringify($scope.far), //forms user object
headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} 
}).
```

**UPDATE:**

Initiliaze the `$scope.far` in the controller before the `$scope.register` function as:

```
$scope.far = {first_name : '', email:'', mobile:''};
```

Comment: I used alert for `$scope.far` after `if` in `controller.js`  its giving undefined instead of Object.@Dev-One

Comment: Why are you stringifying or setting json Content Type? These are done by default by `$http`. Just remove `headers` completely

Comment: Would it be an issue if the user still `stringify` the payload before posting, since its already been handled by `$http`?